# How does y_pred look like when making a custom loss function in keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I am training a UNet shaped CNN and have to deal with data imbalances. I want to minimise false negatives, so I want to implement a custom loss function that does so. I created the following loss function:

```
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

def fbeta_loss(y_true, y_pred, beta=2., epsilon=K.epsilon()):
    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
    
    tp = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
    predicted_positive = K.sum(y_pred_f)
    actual_positive = K.sum(y_true_f)
    
    precision = tp/(predicted_positive+epsilon) # calculating precision
    recall = tp/(actual_positive+epsilon) # calculating recall
    
    # calculating fbeta
    beta_squared = K.square(beta)
    fb = (1+beta_squared)*precision*recall / (beta_squared*precision + recall + epsilon)

    return 1-fb
```

However, I am not sure if y_pred is binary, or a float number between 0 and 1. In my final layer I use a sigmoid activation. Does that mean if I create a custom loss function y_pred is a float between 0 and 1, and I should add a step that maps every value higher then a threshold(0.5) to 1 and lower to 0? Or is that step already included in the Keras model? Since in similar custom loss implementations that step is often not included, [e.g.](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9395) .

Hopefully this is sort of clear, I am relatively new to stackoverflow. Let me know if anything is missing! Thanks in advance.

Comment: y_pred is the output given by your model, without any modifications or further processing.

Comment: Thanks @Dr.Snoopy! I thought so, but I find it weird that common implementation does not include a step to map the probability outcomes to binary. Which is needed for a f1-loss. Do they then use an activation function in the final layer that creates binary output instead of probability outputs? Thanks anyways!

Comment: No, F1 score is not a loss, as it is not differentiable, you cannot use it to train a neural network. The same reason why we do not use accuracy as a loss.

Comment: Hmm oke. So I have used this as a loss function before (with good results) and the people in the link I included do it too, but indeed I also read that it shouldn't be done. So I think you are right and I will not use it anymore. So for class imbalance cases I then should use a weighted cross-entropy loss (to minimise false positives)?

Comment: Also all these loss functions are not differentiable, but still used in a CNN: https://github.com/mlyg/unified-focal-loss/blob/main/loss_functions.py (from this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.04525). Moreover they do not map y_pred from probability to binary... But I understand if you do not want to look into it anymore. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

The output of sigmoid activation function is always between 0 and 1.
[image]

In the limit of x tending towards infinity, S(x) converges to 1, and in the limit of x tending towards negative infinity, S(x) converges to 0. Here, the word *converges* **does not** mean that S(x) reach any of 0 or 1 but it *converges* to 0 and 1.
And so the output of S(x) is always a float **between** 0 and 1.
Range of S(x):
0 < S(x) < 1

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I know that the sigmoid activation is always between 0 and 1, however my question was more on the implementation of a custom loss function in Keras. Does Keras already apply a threshold of 0.5, which causes y_pred to be binary or should I add that step manually? I think the latter, but in many other implementations this step is omitted (see the link I added). I realise my question was a bit unclear, sorry for that.